# Rendering JSON child list from object list in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, dictionary, jsx

I have JSON data like this. I want to render the child object title. But it says "index.js:1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

```
[
  {
    "title": "Components",
    "children": [
      {
        "title": "Buttons",
        "url": "url"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Components",
    "children": [
      {
        "title": "Buttons",
        "url": "url"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I get children title? {data.children.title} does not work.

```
const items = data.map(data => {
        return(
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span>{data.title}</span>
                        <span>{data.children.title}</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    });

    return items;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `children` sub array always has at least one item, then you could render the `title` of the first child item of the current `data` object by the following:

`data.children[0].title`

In your render code, that'd look like this:

```
const items = data.map((data, idx) => (
    <div key={idx}>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span>{data.title}</span>
                <span>{data.children[0].title}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>));

return items;
```

For a more robust alternative, you could check for the existance of an item in the `children` sub-array before rendering by adding chaining a call to `filter()` into your rendering logic:

```
const items = data
/* If children sub-array is non-empty, then it is included
for rendering */
.filter(data => data.children.length > 0)
/* Map any data items that pass filtering */
.map((data, idx) => (
    <div key={idx}>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span>{data.title}</span>
                <span>{data.children[0].title}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>));

return items;
```

Note also, I've include the `key` prop on each `div` that has been mapped of each mapped [as is required when rendering lists](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys), which should resolve the warning that you're seeing in the console. Hope that helps!

#### Update

To render all children per `data` object as a sub-list inside of the `ul` you could do so via an inner mapping of `data.children` to `<li>` elements like this:

```
const items = data
.filter(data => data.children.length > 0)
.map((data, idx) => (
    <div key={idx}>
        {/* 
        I'm assuming data.title should exist outside of 
        children list 
        */}
        <span>{data.title}</span>
        <ul> 
        {   data
            .children
            .map((child, jdx) => (
            <li key={jdx}>
                <span>{child.title}</span>
            </li>))
        }
        </ul>
    </div>));
```

Comment: You will have to give `key` to span tag. Not the `div`

Comment: Thanks! It's work but just one child. How can i get child list?
```
[
  {
    "title": "Components",
    "children": [
      {
        "title": "Buttons",
        "url": "url"
      },
      {
        "title": "Inputs",
        "url": "url"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Components",
    "children": [
      {
        "title": "241451",
        "url": "urdsfl"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: @paws you're welcome :-) I've just updated the answer, hope that helps!

Comment: @DacreDenny thanks a lot! i can speak english just a little but you can understand me! I'm grateful !

Comment: @paws you are very welcome :-)

Comment: @DacreDenny can i ask another question?

Comment: Yes certainly, if you post a new question and send the link to me here I will be happy to help 

Comment: @DacreDenny thank you ! :)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61955420/react-toggle-class

Comment: @DacreDenny could you take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63929343/react-npm-start-doesnt-work-after-create-react-app